# Buffering in Windows Media Player 9

Tags: windows-media-player

Hi I am using Windows Media Player and used to play online music. When I first add the song, it used to buffer the song. During successive plays, it never buffers again. It just plays. Where is the song physically located on the disk? In which format??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the buffered song is stored in RAM and hence is not physically located anywhere on your disk.

Comment: Oh. But even after i restart my PC, it does not buffer again. If it is stored in RAM, it should re-buffer, right?

Comment: That is correct. It might be possible to be buffered by an upstream provider or your browser.